# sed in backtick expansion, with xargs, not substituting the input string

Tags: shell, sed, xargs, backticks

```
echo "who are you" | xargs -i@ echo `echo @ | sed "s/who/where/"`
```

**Expected output**:

```
where are you
```

**actual output**:

```
who are you
```

Note - this is not actual use case but an example test case.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish, and why are you using `xargs` here? The obvious, straightforward, and correct way to do that is simply `echo "who are you" | sed "s/who/where/"`

Comment: ... and a terribly roundabout but nominally correct attempt might be `echo "who are you" | xargs -i@ sh -c 'echo @ | sed "s/who/where/"'`

Comment: i am not trying to accomplish anything, am learning scripting and just wanted to know what's wrong with this one liner.
**hey people pls ignore those backward slashes before tilde.**

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that anything in backticks (or alternatively, the `bash` `$(...)` syntax) is run _before_ the rest of the pipeline. As a result, you're actually running `echo "who are you" | xargs -i@ echo @`, which, as you've noticed, is a bit pointless...

Answer (score 1):

The order of expansion has to be slightly modified:

```
echo "who are you" | echo "`sed "s/who/where/"`" | xargs -I@ echo "@"
```

In your example the command substitution happens before the commands will be started by the shell:

```
echo "who are you" | xargs -i@ echo `echo @ | sed "s/who/where/"`
```

command substitution does this:

```
echo @ | sed "s/who/where/"
```

The result is `"@"` as sed just prints out the input.
Next step is:

```
echo "who are you" | xargs -i@ echo @
```

xargs substitutes `@` with the standard input "who are you" and build and run this command:

```
echo "who are you"
```

So finaly you get the output:

```
who are you
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I'll assume that the actual use case indeed requires `xargs`; the simplest reformulation of the *sample* command would just be `echo 'who are you' | sed 's/who/where/'`</sup>

To get the expected behavior, `xargs` must explicitly call the shell binary `sh` with a string containing a shell command:

```
$ echo "who are you" | xargs -I@ sh -c 'echo "$1" | sed "s/who/where/"' - @
where are you
```

- As [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) points out, in your attempt the command inside `` `...` `` is evaluated *before* `xargs` runs, and it results in a *literal* `@` (due to passing *literal* `@` to `echo`, it simply outputs `@`, because the `sed` command finds nothing to replace), which `xargs` then simply replaces with its input *as-is*; as twalberg states: you're effectively running
  `echo 'who are you' | xargs -i@ echo @`, a virtual no-op, save for potential trimming of leading and trailing whitespace.
- Generally, `xargs` can only call external utilities, and if you need a command that requires *shell* functionality - such as a pipeline - you must explicitly call the shell binary with a *single string* containing shell command(s) - i.e., an ad-hoc script - to be evaluated by that shell instance when called by `xargs`.
- `sh -c` invokes `/bin/sh` with the specified *script* (a string containing shell commands) to evaluate, and it's safest to pass `xargs`' argument as a *positional parameter* to that script; note that the *first* argument after the script binds to `$0` in the script, hence the use of dummy value `_`, followed by `@`, `xargs`'s replacement string, whose expanded value will bind to `$1` inside the script.
- `'echo "$1" | sed "s/who/where/"'` therefore acts as an ad-hoc shell script that pipes its first positional parameter - the argument passed by `xargs` - to `sed` to yield the desired output.

Comment: why using `$1`...? because when I execute `echo "who are you" | xargs -I@ sh -c 'echo "$0" | sed "s/who/where/"' @` I actually get the same output...

Comment: @maxxyme, because the purpose of `$0` is to reflect the _name of the running command_, not to _receive an argument_. Yes, you can repurpose it as you did, but it's not a good idea, especially if you want to process _multiple_ arguments.

Comment: OK I've read this some times, but wouldn't find any relevant examples where this `$0` is of real usage... that's why.

Comment: @maxxyme, `$0` is primarily used for scripts to discover their own name / location (which doesn't apply here). All the argument-handling features, such as `$#` to reflect the argument count, are based on the first argument being stored in `$1`; similarly, `$*`, `"$@"` only contains `$1`, `$2`, ... You could argue that `sh -c` should never have exposed the ability to set `$0` in the first place: it's easy to forget that the first argument after the ad hoc script binds to `$0` - necessitating a dummy argument such as `-` - and, conversely, there's no good reason to set `$0` in this scenario.